# Cancel CountDownTimer when its activity coroutine job is cancelled

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-timer

I have coroutine scope assigned to an activity lifecycle like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
    CoroutineScope
{
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext =
        Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob()
    ...
    
    override fun onDestroy() {
        coroutineContext[Job]!!.cancel()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

Now if I launch a CountDownTimer within this scope, it does not get cancelled when activity is destroyed.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    launch {
        startTimer()
    }
}

fun startTimer(count: Long = 1000) {
    object: CountDownTimer(count, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {}
        override fun onFinish() {
            startTimer()
        }
    }.start()
}
```

Why does it not get cancelled? And how to make it get cancelled specifically by cancelling the activity job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you use a coroutine here, but you can get rid of it, save an instance of `CountDownTimer` to a variable and cancel it in `onDestroy` method:

```
lateinit var timer: CountDownTimer

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    startTimer()
}

fun startTimer(count: Long = 1000) {
    timer = object: CountDownTimer(count, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {}
        override fun onFinish() {
            startTimer()
        }
    }.start()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    timer.cancel()
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

> Why does it not get cancelled?

`CountDownTimer` has its own mechanism of handling ticks, using `Handler`. It is not attached to a coroutine's context.
[Coroutine cancellation is cooperative](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative). A coroutine code has to cooperate to be cancellable. If a coroutine is working in a computation and does not check for cancellation, then it cannot be cancelled.

[There are a couple of approaches](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#making-computation-code-cancellable) to making computation code cancellable:

1. The first one is to periodically invoke a suspending function that checks for cancellation, e.g. `delay`.
2. Explicitly check the cancellation status, e.g. `isActive` or `ensureActive()`.

Comment: I'm aware of this approach but am interested in why it does not work with coroutines.

Comment: it is not designed to work with coroutines, it can work without it. `CountDownTimer` has its own mechanism of handling ticks, using `Handler`.

Comment: It does not need to be `designed` for coroutines. It is just some task which is launched within a coroutine thread and hence is expected to be cancelled together with the parent thread.

Comment: Coroutines should be cooperative to properly handle cancellation. Please see my updated answer. Also here is a good article https://victorbrandalise.com/coroutines-part-iii-structured-concurrency-and-cancellation/

Comment: Replacing CountDownTimer with `delay` solved my needs. Thanks.